# Como pasar un String de Java a Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, html5, servlets

Es un proyecto java web application. Quiero poner un marcador utilizando google maps, yo tengo mi jsp donde lo muestro y tengo el javascript donde utilizo la api. Tengo un java donde hago la conexión a la bd MySQL y otro donde hago la consulta para traer los datos. Hasta acá todo bien.

Ahora, las coordenadas donde quiero poner el marcador están en la bd.

Mi pregunta es, como hago para pasar las coordenadas que ya las traje de la bd y las tengo en el java, al javascript para utilizarlas con la api.

PD. he visto y leído algo sobre que se puede usar servlet y eso pero no termino de entender.

public class Conexion {

```
private static Connection cnx = null;

public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
   if (cnx == null) {
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/deliveryTrackingBD", "root", "root");
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         throw new SQLException(ex);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
      }
   }
   return cnx;
}
```

public class Consulta {

```
private final String tabla = "Pedido";

public Pedido recuperarPorId(Connection conexion, int id) throws SQLException {
   Pedido pedido = null;
   try{
      PreparedStatement consulta = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT Direccion FROM " + this.tabla + " WHERE Id = ?" );
      consulta.setInt(1, id);
      ResultSet resultado = consulta.executeQuery();
      while(resultado.next()){
         pedido = new Pedido(id, resultado.getString("Direccion"));
      }
   }catch(SQLException ex){
      throw new SQLException(ex);
   }
   return pedido;
}
```

Después tengo un index.jsp donde solo tengo el `<div id="map"></div>` para utilizar la api de google map y la referencia al archivo javascript. En este solo tengo lo necesario para la api.

Comment: ¡Hola Juan Manuel! Gracias por la pregunta. La verdad es que la pregunta no es muy clara. Lo que ayudaría mucho es si compartes las partes pertinentes de tu código que se relacionen a tu pregunta para que podamos entender mejor.

Comment: ¿Con qué tecnología web estás desarrollando la app (JSF, JSP,...)?

Comment: Listo, ahí actualicé la pregunta intentando explicarme mejor. Espero que me entiendan.Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes todo tu código Java directo en el JSP en forma de scriptlet, entonces lo que puedes hacer es imprimir el contenido de tu variable `String` directamente en el código JavaScript. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
<html>
<!-- código HTML, CSS, etc -->
<%
    //esto es Java
    String coordenadas = ...; //inicializas coordenadas de alguna manera
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //esto es JavaScript
    function muestraCoordenadas() {
        var coordenadas = "<%= coordenadas %>";
    }
</script>
```

Donde `<%= coordenadas %>` será interpretado por tu JSP y reemplazado por el valor de la variable `coordenadas` de tu scriptlet en Java.

Comment: No, tengo una clase conexion.java donde hago la conexion a la bd y otra consulta.java donde hago las consultas a la bd. Pero se puede de alguna forma llamar a mi código java desde el html <% aca llamar al código java %> como vos pusiste?

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes actualmente. En base a eso te puedo brindar una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Listo, ahí puse parte del código, si precisas algo más avísame. Gracias por tu tiempo.